# 404 Error : Not Found The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server CMS & WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, ftp

Just installed brand new wordpress site via Softalicious on the domain. **[Site Link](http://goldenprincess.fr/wp-admin)** Got message that it was installed successfully.

In the **cPanel > File Manager** I see all my wp files and in mysql admin new database created.

**But I cant access admin area of the site.** I have **404 Error message : Not Found**

```
The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server.
```

I dont see site neither.

```
Hosting provider: amen.fr (French)  - I cant use use other one, it was friend choice for who I make the website.
```

I have done already softalicious installation via other hosting providers - no problem at all!

I wanted to install manually via FTP - impossible. It gave me 530 error everytime I try to connect via Cyberduck or Filezilla : 530 Login failed. But it's it's correct login and password - I verified it in ftp area ten times.

Could you please help me or advice?

Comment: Why do you ask here? Ask the provider! You pay him for the service, he should be the only one with a good and fast answer. Since only the provider can take a real look at the issue.

Comment: I'd love too. But they can be reached only working hours and not on weekend. I need to find the solution this weekend.

Comment: Does not really sounds like a provider I would choose then :-( You might want to post the file hierarchy you created here. Maybe someone knows their strategy in that. Probably you have to use a specific folder name that will be used as root folder. There is really nothing in their documentation about that? Can't believe that...

Comment: @arkascha, wish to choose other provider too. they even dont have phot support. French provider :( Anyway. This is file hierarchy I have in cPanel: http://imgur.com/GMtXzgA does give you an idea?

Comment: Sorry no, that does not ring a bell here... I still say: ask the provider. That fact that they don't offer phone support is not a bad thing. I learned that email support typically gives much more precise answers. And it is not necessarily slower. I certainly prefer that over endless waiting loops and a broken voice I can't really understand :-)